# Everything appears zoomed in

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, display-resolution

I have a problem regarding the screen resolution of my laptop.
My screen broke a few days ago and I had to get it replaced.
However everything appears to be "Zoomed" in now. From log-in at the start, even the head-line where the date and everything is.
Basically, everything is too big now. As if everything was displayed on 120% now.

I suppose it is a result from the laptop being plugged to a 2nd monitor over the process to determine if my screen was broken or the graphics card.
I already checked here and tried a few things that I could find.

Zoom settings are all off. Resolution is set to the maximum.
Several restarts have been done too.

I am a bit unsure what else I could do in order to go back to the normal size, as it is honestly totally annoying to have everything so big.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: might this resource help? http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: Would this work for Ubuntu 18.04 too? The reference images and everything seem to be from older versions. Just thought I might ask before I accidental mess something up.

Comment: Nothing to suggest it won't.

Comment: Hope this does not sound stupid...but what resolution should I change it to? It is currently 1366x768. I was also thinking, do you think it would be a chance to try plugging in a second monitor again? Would have to use our tv, but I was wondering if that might be a way to reverse any resolution changes?

Comment: Not having a laptop I'm not able to help there I'm afraid.